# Wait / sleep miliseconds

Tags: real-time, date-and-time, scheduling

Is there any way to make *Mathematica* stop for some miliseconds?

I know about the `Pause[]` but it seems it only works with seconds.

Comment: "`Pause` is accurate only down to a granularity of at least `$TimeUnit` seconds." - which is `0.001` so you are lucky.

Comment: So I can use Pause[0.5] for example?

Comment: @Trollkemada On my system `{Mean@#, StandardDeviation@#} &@
 Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[Pause[0.123]], {10}]` returns `{0.123241, 0.00003}`. So, at least in some situations, it seems quite reliable. Just don't rely on it for "hard real time" applications.

Comment: @Kuba I wouldn't close the question as this is not a trivial topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is: no, Mathematica is simply not suitable for time-critical applications.

---

There are several reasons for this:

- Mathematica is a slow interpreted language and the time taken by various operations can be close to your threshold of milliseconds
- There are several things that may interrupt the Mathematica kernel while it's doing calculations, including [`ScheduledTasks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScheduledTasks.html) and other preemptive evaluations from GUI elements (see [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html))
- Mathematica's time measurement functions are simply not precise, as the underlying system calls it uses are not meant for precision applications.

Regarding [`$TimeUnit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24TimeUnit.html): this variable is supposed to give the granularity of both `Pause` and time measurement functions such as `AbsoluteTiming` and `Timing`.  One thing to be aware here is that its value varies between operating systems (I get 1/100 on OS X and 1/1000 on Windows).  Another is that *it is simply not precise or reliable*.  For example, on Windows XP with Mathematica 8 it returns 1/1000.  However the true granularity on Windows XP is 15 milliseconds, i.e. 15/1000.  (On Vista and later the same system function Mathematica uses really does have a granularity of 1 ms.) On OS X / Mathematica 9, the true granularity seems to be 1 ms even though `$TimeUnit` is 1/100.

Comment: I agree, well, imo OP was not clear enough so without anyone who could kindly elaborate vague topic it was meant to be closed. But now I;ve retracted closevote. +1.