# control Dynamic speed

Tags: front-end, dynamic

Some animations are more suitable to use `Dynamic` instead of `Animate`, the following code is minimized.

The refresh rate is a little slow, although I have set `UpdateInterval -> 0`, it takes about 20 sec, I want it to be 5 to 10 sec.

```
L = {}; 
i = 0;
Dynamic[If[i < 1000, AppendTo[L, RandomReal[1, 2]]; i++, UpdateInterval -> 0]; 
Graphics[{Point@L}, PlotLabel -> i]
]
```

The refresh rate of following version is too fast, I know I can make it slower by adding `Pause[$TimeUnit]`, but when I added it, it was a bit slow, later I thought I could use `(10^5)!` instead of `Pause`, this is not elegant, is there any other better way?

```
L = {};
i = 0;
Dynamic@Graphics[{Point@L}, PlotLabel -> i]
While[++i < 10^3,
 AppendTo[L, RandomReal[1, 2]]; 
 (*(10^5)!*)
]
```

Related link: [Wait / sleep miliseconds](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43818/wait-sleep-miliseconds)